# asm.js - Microsoft Edge browser release channel

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Are there any references as to if and when Microsoft plans to enable asm.js in Microsoft edge release channel by default?

Currently it can be activated by going to "about:flags" and enabling it.  What I want to know is if there are plans to enable it by default.

*EDIT/UPDATE:

http://techdows.com/2015/08/asm-js-enabled-by-default-in-microsoft-edge-browser-in-windows-10-build-10532.html

Enabled by default in preview build, but not RTM yet.*

Comment: since asm is just a string flag - why are you are interested? Just being curious?

Comment: @Patrick It's currently not just a flag.  There are some optimizations that make a clear difference in real world code.  In theory, the optimizations can be made to not be asm.js specific like in Chrome/V8, but not ATM.

Comment: It's a flag that turns on those optimizations

Comment: @Patrick what did you mean by "string" flag?

Comment: it is a string that it added to the file that acts as a flag to enable a feature.

Comment: @Patrick can you provide an example?  If you are referring to "use asm" that only works if you go to about:flags and enable it.  It is off by default.

Comment: yes. "use asm". I was referring to the fact that there is essentially no overhead in adding it. That being said, asm support was released by default today.

Comment: @Patrick thanks for the info.  FYI I am working on web apps using computationally intensive code that performs too poorly in Edge without asm.js opt.  With this I know I can ship my product as "beta" for Edge/Chrome/FF, and wait for Edge to catch up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, asm.js will be enabled in Microsoft Edge release by default as stated [here](http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/05/07/bringing-asm-js-to-chakra-microsoft-edge/) (most relevant piece copied below). We do not currently have a committed timeline to share but are continuing to work through the process described below. The easiest way to stay up-to-date is to look for it to be on-by-default in our preview [Windows Insider builds](https://insider.windows.com) or follow [the status on our public roadmap](http://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/asmjs/).

*"We are working on fine tuning Chakra’s pipeline for ASM.js support – gathering data to validate if the current design approach performs well for real world asm.js payloads, understanding and addressing outstanding performance, functionality and tooling issues etc. before enabling this feature by default.*